# Loop through JSON response - Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have a JSON response from the server that looks like this:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "disabled": false,
            "condition": [
                "or",
                [
                    "contains",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "custom_details",
                        "resolved"
                    ],
                    "Platform"
                ],
                [
                    "contains",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "custom_details",
                        "firing"
                    ],
                    "Platform"
                ]
            ],
            "catch_all": false,
            "advanced_condition": [],
            "actions": [
                [
                    "route",
                    "XYZ123"
                ],
                [
                    "extract",
                    "^\\[.*\\] *([^ ]*)",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "summary"
                    ],
                    "description"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "9876",
            "disabled": false,
            "condition": [
                "or",
                [
                    "contains",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "custom_details",
                        "resolved"
                    ],
                    "Sidewalk"
                ],
                [
                    "contains",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "custom_details",
                        "firing"
                    ],
                    "Sidewalk"
                ]
            ],
            "catch_all": false,
            "advanced_condition": [],
            "actions": [
                [
                    "route",
                    "QWERT1"
                ],
                [
                    "extract",
                    "^\\[.*\\] *([^ ]*)",
                    [
                        "path",
                        "payload",
                        "summary"
                    ],
                    "description"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to loop over this and match the string `Sidewalk`. If there is a match, then get the value of `id` of the matched.

I tried this

```
---
- name: API call - GET Event Rule ID
  uri:
   url: "{{ api_event_rules }}"
    method: GET
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/vnd.ap+json;version=2"
      Authorization: "Token token={{ api_token }}"
  register: json_response
```

I tried this JMESPath

```
rules[*].condition[*][2]
```

But this gives out something like this:

```
[
[
  "Platform",
  "Platform"
],
[
  "Sidewalk",
  "Sidewalk"
],
```

I'm not able to find my way past this, very new to ansible. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: "Match the string Sidewalk. If there is a match, then get the value of id of the matched."

A: It's not clear which 'Sidewalk' we shall look for. Let's take first one. The task below creates a dictionary of *id* and the corresponding condition

```
- set_fact:
    ids: "{{ rules|
            json_query('[*].{key: condition[1][2], value: id}')|
            items2dict
            }}"
- debug:
    var: ids['Sidewalk']
```

The debug gives

```
"ids['Sidewalk']": "9876"
```

If this shall be a conditional task the debug below

```
- debug:
    msg: "Sidewalk found with id: {{ ids['Sidewalk'] }}"
  when: "'Sidewalk' in ids.keys()"
```

gives

```
"msg": "Sidewalk found with id: 9876"
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, thanks for your answer. I tried this, getting a `FAILED! => {"msg": "items2dict requires a list, got <type 'NoneType'> instead."}`

Comment: Make sure what you feed json_query with. To debug it, remove the filter items2dict and see what you get 'var: ids'.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, got it.